# How to apply a pseudo class to some elements in LESS

Tags: css, reactjs, less

I don't know if I named the title right or have the right terminology but I'm using LESS.

What I want is to apply arrows on some `<ul>`s while the default is no style. So anytime I want arrows, I want to somehow explicitly say so in code.

I tried adding a pseudo class called `.arrow`:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  .arrow{
    content: "";
    border-color: transparent #111;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: -1em;
    top: 0.9em;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Then tried to apply it like this:

```
<ul className="arrow">
    <li><span className="ink-badge black small">Consulting</span></li>
</ul>
```

but no luck. I'm not doing this right; any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`className` is the IDL attribute. In HTML you should use the content attribute, which is called `class`.

And `.arrow` is a class selector, not a pseudo-class.

And in selectors, place ancestors at the left (outer block in LESS).

```css
body {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.arrow > li {
  content: "";
  border-color: transparent #111;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.35em 0 0.35em 0.45em;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -1em;
  top: 0.9em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="arrow">
  <li><span class="ink-badge black small">Consulting</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: className is for React.js.

Comment: also I want to take advantage of less.  All you show is plain css, surely there is a pattern or something to make this nicer with less?  pseudo class, or something like that

Comment: @WTF If you are using some custom library or framework which converts `className` content attributes to `class` then tag your question properly. I used plain CSS because stack snippets don't compile LESS (and what's the point of using it in this simple case?), but I included it in the explanation.